# How to add Metro web services support to Eclipse Indigo

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, glassfish, jax-ws

[Arun Gupta has a nice tutorial](http://blog.arungupta.me/2009/08/totd-98-create-a-metro-jax-ws-web-service-using-glassfish-tools-bundle-for-eclipse/) where he can choose Metro from the web services runtimes list. I don't have that option in this list, and so I can't make Metro web services with the wizard:

[image: Web services runtimes]

I have already installed Oracle GlassFish Server Tools. Has anybody done this? If yes, how? Please if you have some best practices or suggestions feel free to share!

**EDIT** I found the [instructions](http://ajax.java.net/eclipse/) about how to correctly install the GlassFish plugin, but the update site `https://ajax.dev.java.net/eclipse` is dead.

Reinstalled the plugin as presented [here](http://glassfishplugins.java.net/eclipse36/index.html#getting), but no success.

Comment: all of the things that you referencing are very old 'in code years'.  It seems like this is a part of the Eclipse/GlassFish integration that hasn't seen much usage. This may be a situation where code entropy has set in.

Comment: @vkraemer Thanks for your reply! The version of `Oracle GlassFish Server Tools` is `2.0.1.201214031503`, so according to the date part it is not an abandoned project. Still, I hate this; all the documentation related to the GlassFish project is outdated.

Comment: The plugin that adds the 'METRO (JAX-WS) Runtime' is based on the java.net project http://java.net/projects/metroplugineclipse.  It has not been active for a couple years.  I have started to look at updating the project to build against a recent release of Metro, Jersey and Eclipse... I will have another update as I make progress on updating the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

Look over this

http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/webservices_jaxws/

This is jax-ws metro lib, you don't need to have GlassFish. Tomcat will do.

They added Metro JAX-WS run-time libraries.

I have tried this, and it works.

Comment: This is a MyEclipse guide, and if I understand correctly MyEclipse and Eclipse are different IDEs with a lot in common. So: did you try this with Eclipse Indigo?

Comment: I wanted to get quick feel for jax-ws soap and rest. I did not try with Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: Danieal, wrote simple service and ran it over Eclipse Indigo.

Answer (score 0):

For Eclipse Indigo.

Create Java project

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
@WebService
public class WSResponse {
    public String getMessage(String name){
    return "Hello "+name;
    }
}
//Create build.xml
<project default="wsgen">
<target name="wsgen" >
<exec executable="wsgen">
<arg line="-cp ./bin -keep -s ./src -d ./bin com.ws.service.example.WSResponse"/>
</exec>
</target>
</project>
```

Execute Ant build.xml file

Finally Write: WS-publishing class

```
import javax.xml.ws.Endpoint;
public class RunWSService {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Startring Web Service started.");
    Endpoint.publish("http://localhost:8080/WSExample", new WSResponse());
}
}
```

Test it with Web Service Explorer.